# .NET - is it possible to run an out of process COM Server in a WinForms app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, com, com-server

I want to run a COM Server (out of process) as part of a WinForms application - targeting .NET 2.0

The sample code I found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977996 uses a message loop, which will most likely interfere with the WinForms app

Is it possible to create a COM server inside a WinForms app? My backup plan is to use a stand-alone COM server EXE (as per the example), and send info to my app through named pipes WCF calls, but I would prefer not to do that due to the overhead of installing and managing another application.

Thanks!

Comment: This feels like a Windows Service... have you considered that approach at all? Cute dog, btw :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to cast COM object of type '...' to interface type '...' while using an ExeCOMServer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750947/unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-to-interface-type-while-using-an-e)